# How can I verify which github repo a github token from a github action is coming from?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I have an API that is being called from a long running github action. There is a github token, `GITHUB_TOKEN`, which can be sent with requests to my API, but I can't find a way to verify which repo the token came from.  Environment variable `GITHUB_REPOSITORY` is set in the action and I can ferry that along into my API, but I can't be certain that a bad actor isn't using a *different* github action and simply injecting their own `GITHUB_REPOSITORY`and sending it along to my API.

I tried to call `https://api.github.com/user` like:

```
curl --header 'authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' \
      https://api.github.com/user
```

but it responds:

```
{
  "message": "Resource not accessible by integration",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#get-the-authenticated-user"
}
```

I can only do certain github api calls with a token for the *wrong* repo, but many of these actions work for public github repos.

---

Given a `GITHUB_TOKEN`, how can I validate which repo the action token is from in both public and private repo actions?  I'd prefer to do this in a read-only fashion. If I have to, I'll do it with some silly write to the repo which only github-actions *for that repo* may do, hopefully followed by an immediate erasure of my write.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the threat model yet. Since `GITHUB_TOKEN`s are repository-scoped, if a bad actor injected their own `GITHUB_REPOSITORY` then the `GITHUB_TOKEN` wouldn't work.

Comment: Maybe you're really looking for validation that you're running in a particular repository, and you're trying to use the token to validate _that_ knowledge and not the other way around?

Comment: @EdwardThomson, That is correct (and apologies for miscommunication).  I'm looking to validate which repository I'm running _against_.  The `GITHUB_TOKEN` has access to _other_ public repositories' github REST API.   Is there any endpoint that will reliably fail if the `GITHUB_TOKEN` does _not_ correlate with the supplied `GITHUB_REPOSITORY`?

Comment: No apologies necessary; I just wanted to make sure that I understood your use case. I'm glad you've found a workaround. I'll think about this as we make improvements to the github context that we provide during workflow execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not official and maybe it will change, but if you hit the [`collaborators` endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/collaborators#list-repository-collaborators) it appears to fail if you try any repo other than the repo for which the `GITHUB_TOKEN` was issued:

```
curl -vv --header 'authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' \
      https://api.github.com/repos/django/django/collaborators?per_page=1
```

Responds:

```
HTTP/2 403 
[...]
{
  "message": "Resource not accessible by integration",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#list-repository-collaborators"
}
```

---

github support suggests using `https://api.github.com/installation/repositories` which should only return the github repository the token was issued from.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an OIDC token?

This is an example of data it contains:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "example-thumbprint",
  "kid": "example-key-id"
}
{
  "jti": "example-id",
  "sub": "repo:octo-org/octo-repo:environment:prod",
  "environment": "prod",
  "aud": "https://github.com/octo-org",
  "ref": "refs/heads/main",
  "sha": "example-sha",
  "repository": "octo-org/octo-repo",
  "repository_owner": "octo-org",
  "actor_id": "12",
  "repository_visibility": private,
  "repository_id": "74",
  "repository_owner_id": "65",
  "run_id": "example-run-id",
  "run_number": "10",
  "run_attempt": "2",
  "actor": "octocat",
  "workflow": "example-workflow",
  "head_ref": "",
  "base_ref": "",
  "event_name": "workflow_dispatch",
  "ref_type": "branch",
  "job_workflow_ref": "octo-org/octo-automation/.github/workflows/oidc.yml@refs/heads/main",
  "iss": "https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com",
  "nbf": 1632492967,
  "exp": 1632493867,
  "iat": 1632493567
}
```

Please refer the below link :

[hardening with OpenID Connect](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect)