# How to verify if a request is from github action

Tags: github-actions

I want to get some data from my own server in github action, and I want to know that is this request come from github.

So I tried to send the `secret.GITHUB_TOKEN` to my server and then use it to request a github api on my server. but I always got a `Bad credentials` response from github api

I tried :

1. `https://api.github.com/repos/my_org/repo_name`
2. `https://api.github.com/repos/my_org/repo_name/actions/runs/run_id`

an example of my request:

```
$ curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ghs_xxxxxxxxx"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/my_org_name/repo_name

{
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
```

then I found an answer from here [How can I verify which github repo a github token from a github action is coming from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71864756/how-can-i-verify-which-github-repo-a-github-token-from-a-github-action-is-coming). but still the same result.

PS:

1. thie repo is in an orgnization.
2. it is a private repo.

I have so many repos' action need to request my server, so I don't want to set a const secret in each repo to verify the source of request.

workflow:

```
name: test

on:
#  workflow_dispatch:
  push:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: test token
        run: |
          curl "http://myhost.com/test_token?github_token=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```

the log on my server(written by `gin`):

```
[GIN] 2023/07/14 - 18:36:59 | 200 |  544.258381ms |   13.87.245.228 | GET      "/test_token?github_token=ghs_xxxxxxxxxxxj57s6QIdsF34Y15Ix"
```

`ghs_xxxxxxxxxxxj57s6QIdsF34Y15Ix` is the token I use

UPDATE:

more test:

```
$curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ghs_xxxxxxxxxxxj57s6QIdsF34Y15Ix"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/org_name/repo_name/actions/workflows/test.yaml
{
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out this, and the reason is just becase: token will expired when workflow finished